# How work history of web browser under the hood

Tags: algorithm, web, data-structures, browser, browser-history

I am trying to implement my own web browser history for WKWebView on iOS, but I can't implement this functionality completely, and each time I obtain trouble.
I can create a history where the user did be and then moving forward and backward inside history.
But I have next trouble, and I think it an only one of many problems on my way.
When I have a history with for example 10 elements, and then I am moving back to element number 5 and then go don't forward but try to open the new link I can't remove element 6-10 and put the new link.

I think my problem that I can't fully understand how history work inside all browsers under the hood, this is not a hard task but I am confused inside this algorithm.
My main data structure for holding history 
Help me understand how to work this algorithm inside browsers or maybe exist a good theory about it?

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. If someone is at element 5 and visits a new page, just remove elements 6-10 and add a new element 6. You can do that with either a linked-list or an array.

Comment: Theoretically, this is not hard, but during the realization, complexity is growing up. I don't fully understand how must work a finished history algorithm. Therefore I obtain problems when moving between history and when I want to go to a new page staying inside the middle of history my history get confused.

Comment: I mean, isn't it just this: back: `currentPosition--`, forward: `currentPosition++`, visit new page: `history.remove(currentPosition + 1, history.length()); history.add(newPage); currentPosition++`? (That's pseudo-code, `remove` removes elements between the given indices).

Comment: I have solved the problem using your advice, thank you :) At the current moment, all algorithm works well, when I will finish all tasks, I will post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem and realize the full algorithm well, the completed project available here: https://github.com/IhorYachmenov/Custom-browser-history-for-WKWebView.

Algorithm:

```
struct PlayerHistory {
    
    static var shared = PlayerHistory()
    
    var historyExist: Bool = false
    var historyCurrentPosition: Int = 0
    var historyLastPositionBeforeUpdatingHistory: Int!
    var userHistoryKey: String!
    
    var backPressed: Bool!
    var forwardPressed: Bool!
    
    var urlOfPlayer: String!
    
    // Function only for first loading inside <viewDidLoad or another method from app LifeCycle>.
    mutating func getUrlForFirstLoading(initURL: String, key: String) -> String {
        
        urlOfPlayer = initURL
        
        guard HistoryStorage.shared.getHistoryFromUserDefaults() != nil else {
            updateFirstElement(key: key, url: initURL)
            return initURL
        }
        
        guard HistoryStorage.shared.getHistoryFromUserDefaults()![key] != nil else {
            return initURL
        }
        
        let position = HistoryStorage.shared.getHistoryFromUserDefaults()![key]!.count - 1
        
        historyExist = true
        historyCurrentPosition = position
        userHistoryKey = key
        let initUrlFromHistoryStorage = HistoryStorage.shared.getHistoryFromUserDefaults()![key]!.last!.url
        
        return initUrlFromHistoryStorage
    }
    
    // Create new or update exist history, use this method indsede <decidePolicyForNavigation>.
    mutating func updatePlayerHistory(backlisk: [String], key: String) {
        
        var history = [WebViewHistory]()
        
        for i in backlisk {
            history.append(WebViewHistory(i))
        }
        
        if (historyExist == true) {
            // If old history exist need compound both and then to save.
            
            let oldHistory = HistoryStorage.shared.getHistoryFromUserDefaults()![key]

            let oldAndNewHostoryTogether = oldHistory! + history
            
            var keyValuePair = Dictionary<String, [WebViewHistory]>()
            keyValuePair.updateValue(oldAndNewHostoryTogether, forKey: key)
            
            HistoryStorage.shared.removeHistory()
            HistoryStorage.shared.saveHistory(keyValuePair)
            
            setCurrentPosition(url: backlisk.last!, key: key)
        } else {
            var keyValuePair = Dictionary<String, [WebViewHistory]>()
            keyValuePair.updateValue(history, forKey: key)
            
            historyExist = true
            
            HistoryStorage.shared.removeHistory()
            HistoryStorage.shared.saveHistory(keyValuePair)
            setCurrentPosition(url: backlisk.last!, key: key)
        }
    }
        
    
    // Before using this method check if result don't equals nil. Use this method for navigation beetween history
    func moveThroughHistory(key: String, direction: Bool) -> String? {
        
        guard  historyExist != false else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let history = HistoryStorage.shared.getHistoryFromUserDefaults()![key]!
        
        if (direction == true) {
            let index = historyCurrentPosition + 1
            guard index != history.count else { return nil }
            return history[index].url
        } else {
            let index = historyCurrentPosition - 1
            guard index > 0 else { return history[0].url }
            return history[index].url
        }
        
        
    }
    
    // Method <setCurrentPosition> each time set position at history
    mutating func setCurrentPosition(url: String, key: String) {
        
        guard HistoryStorage.shared.getHistoryFromUserDefaults() != nil else { return }
        guard HistoryStorage.shared.getHistoryFromUserDefaults()![key] != nil else { return }
        
        let history = HistoryStorage.shared.getHistoryFromUserDefaults()![key]
        let index = history?.firstIndex(of: WebViewHistory(url))
        
        guard index != nil else {
            historyCurrentPosition = 0
            return
        }
        historyCurrentPosition = index!
    }
    
    // <removeUnusedPeaceOfHistory> need use when user want open new page staying inside the middle of history
    mutating func removeUnusedPeaceOfHistory(key: String) {
        
        guard HistoryStorage.shared.getHistoryFromUserDefaults() != nil else {
            return
        }
        
        guard HistoryStorage.shared.getHistoryFromUserDefaults()![key] != nil else {
            return
        }
        
        var history = HistoryStorage.shared.getHistoryFromUserDefaults()![key]!
        let startIndex = historyCurrentPosition + 1
        let endIndex = history.endIndex - 1
        let countOfAllElements = history.count
        
        guard startIndex != countOfAllElements else { return }
        let range = startIndex...endIndex
        history.removeSubrange(range)
        
        var keyValuePair = Dictionary<String, [WebViewHistory]>()
        keyValuePair.updateValue(history, forKey: key)
        
        HistoryStorage.shared.removeHistory()
        HistoryStorage.shared.saveHistory(keyValuePair)
    }
        
    // Use <updateFirstElement> inside <getUrlForFirstLoading> if history doesn't exist
    private mutating func updateFirstElement(key: String, url: String) {
        var history = [WebViewHistory]()
        history.insert(WebViewHistory(url), at: 0)
        
        var keyValuePair = Dictionary<String, [WebViewHistory]>()
        keyValuePair.updateValue(history, forKey: key)
        
        HistoryStorage.shared.saveHistory(keyValuePair)
        historyExist = true
        historyCurrentPosition = 0
        
    }
    
    // Use <webViewWillBeClosedSaveHistory> when WKWebView should be closed, if the user moves through history new position will be saved.
    mutating func webViewWillBeClosedSaveHistory(key: String) {
        let history = HistoryStorage.shared.getHistoryFromUserDefaults()![key]!
        let currentPosition = historyCurrentPosition + 1
        guard currentPosition != history.count else { return }
        removeUnusedPeaceOfHistory(key: key)
    }
}
```